# Query to compare two year sales

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with these columns:

- Year
- Month
- Product
- Qty

Example:

```
Year   Month  Product  Qty
2011   1      XYZQW     45
```

So in this table was stored all product sales.

I need to build a query to compare one year and its previous to build this report:

```
Year   GEN FEB MAR APR MAY GIU JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC 
-------------------------------------------------------
2011    12  23  56  54  14  11  15  18  89  87  48  98
2012    19  21  55  50  24  10  19  17  88  81  45  90
```

There is a way to do this without creating a temporary table?

Comment: It is called `pivot`.  Learn about it here (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, try this:

```
WITH DT(AMonth,AYear,AQty)
     AS (SELECT Month, Year, Qty
         FROM YourTable)
SELECT pvt.*
FROM     DT cte
         PIVOT
         (SUM(AQty)
          FOR AYear IN ( [2011],[2012],[2013],[2014] ) ) AS pvt
```